# Generate a CGPath from another path's line width outline

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgpath

I might not be explaining this in the best way possible, so please bear with me.

What I have is a drawn CGPath on top of a MKMapView object:

[image]

The way I was able to achieve this is to create a CGPath for the darker blue line, then create a copy of that path, and then stroke a thicker version of it with a semi-transparent blue color. Here's the code that I'm currently using for this:

```
    // set the shadow around the path line
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.4f);
    CGPathRef shadowPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(self.path.CGPath, NULL, 80.0f, kCGLineCapRound, kCGLineJoinRound, 0.0f);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, shadowPath);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    CGPathRelease(shadowPath);
```

Works pretty well, nothing wrong so far.

However, what I would like to do though is to get a CGPathRef of the outline of that thicker semi-transparent blue area. Here's another screenshot showing the pseudo-path that I want out of this (hand drawn in red):

[image]

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: just use [`CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath).  Pass in a wide line width, and a cap of `kCGLineCapRound`.

Comment: Kurt, that's exactly how I am already generating this outline with a semi-transparent blue color. What I want though is to get a CGPath of that outline, if that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you could draw a picture of what exactly you want, then? I'm not  entirely sure what you mean by "outline". If you want another stroke around that path, then call `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath` again.

Comment: Kurt, I just updated the question with a clarification on the code that I'm already using. I also included another screenshot with the outline path in red.

Comment: @jpm Could you write out the solution? I have exactly the same problem. I tried CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath, but got the following result: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3400922/Screenshots/74.png

Comment: @PavelAlexeev Aha, great question. My results were exactly the same, and after countless hours wasted trying to figure out where the bug in my code was, I opened a DTS ticket with Apple. Turns out that CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath has a bug that generates this weird looking outline path. They asked me to check if the bug was still present in iOS 7, but I did not have time yet to do so. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw two stokes.

one stroke with width n (which n is the outline width) and black color.
another stroke is then drawn on top of the first one, with eraser mode:

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
```